# ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I noticed a lot of answers is to install jest-jasmine2 and add **testRunner: 'jasmine2'** into jest.test.config.

I added this, but it is still not working. Below is my test case:

```
it('test', async () => {
        const submitForm = jest.fn();
        const st = mount(
            <MyComponent
                {...{ submitForm }}
            />,
   
        );

        st.find('form').simulate('submit');
  
        expect(submitForm).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ isValid: false, values: jasmine.anything() });
    });
```

Error:
ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined

```
  91 |         await nextTick();
  92 |
> 93 |         expect(**submitForm**).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ isValid: false, values: jasmine.anything() });
     |                                                                           ^
  94 |     });
```

Comment: Why don't you use the expectations that _Jest_ exposes? https://jestjs.io/docs/expect

Comment: Did u fix this issue ? I am facing the same error now